# How to strip 25 to just 5 using javascript?

Tags: javascript

if i have a number like 25 for example, i would like to use javascript to "knock off" the 2 and keep the 5.

Same for any number - i want the 9 from the 89.

But i also want it to not do this if the number is single like an 8 for example

Thanks in advance,

Reece

Comment: Your specs look fairly incomplete: what about `123`, `-1`, `a1`...? Is it a `Number` or a `String`?

Answer (score 8):

Use the modulo operator, it returns the "rest" after a division:

`lastDigit = number % 10;`

Answer (score 4):

You could use modulus:

```
var number = 89;
var reminder = number % 10; // 9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the modulus operator (%):

```
var num = 89 % 10; // 9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var number = 25;
var singledigit = number%10;
```